# Какая разница между языком программирования в Delphi 7 и современным Delphi для создании приложений под Android?

Tags: delphi

Подскажите есть ли разница в языке который используется в Delphi 7 и в Multi-devise application (создание приложения для андроид), ведь там и там язык делфи?

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит двояко: с одной стороны - да, язык тот же. Т.е. синтаксис и правила написания кода не отличаются... Но со времен Delphi 7 появились новые конструкции (например - дженерики) и структура классов в FMX достаточно сильно отличается от того, к чему вы привыкли в VCL.

Comment: вас возможности компилятора интересуют, или вообще все компоненты, а-ля упомянутых VCL/FMX ?

Answer (score 1):

В современных Delphi XE+ и Delphi 10+ для андроида не VCL, а другая визуальная библиотека компонентов - Firemonkey. Язык Паскаль тот же самый, с добавлением небольшого числа новых плюшек.